# Is there a way of getting all of the changes of an entity with the Entity History?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, entities

So I've enabled Entity History. Was trying to use the EntitySnapshotManager to get changes but;

First of all I was unable to, not changes were ever being brought back, maybe I need to specific the specific time and date a change was made?

Secondly I believe it'll only bring back whatever changes were made on that date/time and I want to use this EntityHistory data to have a table of the overall history of a record.

Before I create my own EntityHistoryManager that'll use the repositories to generate a list of changes to an Entity is there something built into Abp that'll already handle this? Seems a bit odd to have an Entity History without being able to get the whole history of an Entity.

Cheers!

Comment: Read the documentation: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History

Comment: *`IEntitySnapshotManager.GetSnapshotAsync(...)` returns an `EntityHistorySnapshot` that contains the snapshot value of all changed properties on the given date and a stack tree of the changes.*

Comment: I did I was just hoping it wasn't so limited and there was a way to get all the changes to a Entity since it was created.

Comment: That's what the repository already does. Why would you expect a snapshot manager to do that?